# Excel Macro Nearest Neighbor

Tags: excel, nearest-neighbor, vba

I have a Microsoft Excel document with 4 sheets. Within each sheet there are 21 rows and approximately 500 columns. I am trying to write a nearest neighbor function to fill all cells in these sheets that have a particular value.

Example row data layout:

> 1. 25 41 54 54 XX 41 54 XX XX XX 54 14
> 2. 23 88 33 XX 41 54 XX 87 48 65 77 14

I need to go through all of the data and replace the XXs with their closest row neighbor. I figure this can be done with a nested `for` loop going through each value (each column in each row) and seeing if that current cell is an XX. If so, it should grab the nearest neighbor without an XX value.

Comment: To clarify, when you say "nearest row neighbour", you mean the nearest value within the same row?  I.e. ignoring any potentially closer vertical neighbours?  Also, how would you like to resolve cases where there are multiple nearest neighbours, like the first `XX` in your example?

Comment: Cool question, but you have to be MUCH more specific about what you mean by "nearest neighbor" - What about XX's at the ends (Left / Right / Top / Bottom - Depending on how you define nearest neighbor again)

Comment: my apologies, I meant nearest neighbor in the row. There are cases when there are XXXXs at the beginning and the end, in these cases, I wanted to have them populated by the closest non-X value in the row

Answer (score 0):

I will take a shot at this... but keep in mind that since you didn't respond to the requests for clarification, this may not be exactly what you had in mind. Also I'm doing this without access to a machine that runs VBA so there may be a trivial bug or two.

```
Option Explicit
sub fillNN()
' we know there are five rows; number of columns is "approximate".
dim thisRow as Integer
dim s, c
dim r, rLast as range

for each s in WorkBook.WorkSheets
  s.Activate
  set r = Range("A1")

  For thisRow = 1 To 5
    set r = Range("A1").Offset(thisRow-1,0)
    set rLast = r.End(xlToRight) ' find the last cell in the row

    for each c in Range(r, rLast).cells
      if c.Value = "XX" Then
        c.Value = nearestNeighbor(c)
      end if
    next c
  Next thisRow

  ' the nearestNeighbor() function left the "XX" on the value
  ' now we have to strip it:
  For thisRow = 1 To 5
    set r = Range("A1").Offset(thisRow-1,0)
    set rLast = r.End(xlToRight) ' find the last cell in the row

    for each c in Range(r, rLast).cells
      if Left(c.Value, 2) = "XX" Then
        c.Value = MID(c.Value, 3, len(c.Value)-2)
      end if
    next c
  Next thisRow

Next s
End Sub

Function nearestNeighbor(c as Range)
' find the nearest "valid" cell:
' look to the left and to the right; if nothing found, extend the range by 1 and repeat
Dim rc, cc , dr, cs, s as Integer
Dim lastCol as Integer
Dim flag as Boolean
flag = true
s = 1 ' size of step

lastCol = c.End(xlToRight).column

' if c is the last cell, then the above will go to the end of the spreadsheet
' since we know there are "about 500" columns, we can catch that easily:
if lastCol > 1000 Then lastCol = c.column

' make sure there is always a return value:
nearestNeighbor = "XX"
While (flag)
  For dr = -1 To 1 Step 2
    cs = c.column + dr * s
    If Not(cs < 1 Or cs > lastCol) Then
      If Not c.offset(dr * s, 0).Value = "XX" Then
        flag = false
        ' keep the "XX" in front so it won't become a "valid nearest neighbor" on next pass
        nearestNeighbor = "XX" + c.offset(dr * s, 0).Value
        Exit For
      End If
    End If
  Next dr
  s = s + 1
  if s > lastCol Then flag = false
End While

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

Assuming your data is like below image.

[image]

code :

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Cells.Find("XX")

    Do Until rng Is Nothing
        rng.Value = rng.Offset(0, -1) 'Offset(0, -1) for left neighbour  , Offset(0, 1) for right
        Set rng = Cells.Find("XX")
    Loop
End Sub
```